# Localized Date Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to use user's culture to localize the Range Validator for date? I am looking for a good way to validate date and avoiding to provide a fix format (e.g.: do a dd/mm/yyyy using Regular Expression Validator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be something closest to what I want actually.

Getting user's language preference based on language settings:

```
userLanguage = Request.UserLanguages[0];
```

Get `ShortDatePattern` base on language:

```
new CultureInfo(userLanguage).DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

From here I will use the pattern to validate user's input and to display the required format on the page.

Comment: Ignore the above unless you want to do your own Custom Control. Otherwise to use CompareValidator, just add 2 things to your code.
1. set CultureInvarientValues = true;
2. set the culture in web.config or just the page. e.g. <globalization culture="en-GB"/> under <system.web> in web.config.
3. to use calendar extender, set the pattern to CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern.

that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Date.TryParseExact()` method, consulting the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx).
Use members of the returned `My.Application.Culture.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat` object, which is of class System.Globalization.[DateTimeFormatInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx), to retrieve the date formats for the current culture (there are several formats for every culture, such as long format and short format...).

Comment: Thanks Hanin, I guess we will fit this approach into CustomValidator?